# Finding difference between column from select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to output the difference between my calculation in a SQL statement.

Let's say I have the following select statement and tables:

'''
Select SUM(a) as A, case as B, 0 as diff
where ......
'''

the thing I'm trying to do is to use A - B as diff but currently have no luck on it.

Anything is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For your case a **Common Table Expression** could be helpful:

```sql
WITH
  cte AS (Select SUM(a) as A, case as B where ...)
SELECT A, B, (A-B) ar diff FROM cte
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html